# Fuel SDK | Python | rename data extension field name/attribute name

Tags: marketing-cloud, fuel-sdk, python

Is it possible to update the Field name of an existing data extension using Fuel SDK?

> > My requirement: Change field name from '**Country**' to '**Country_code**'

I was able to get the CustomerKey of required column name using below,
[Retrieve Data Extension Column Details](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/data-extension-column-retrieve.html)

However using the field CustomerKey upon trying to re-name the field a New field gets created or getting error as

> StatusMessage = "A field named Country_code already exists on object Vishal_FuelDE. "

Below is the code I am trying,

```python
import FuelSDK
myClient = FuelSDK.ET_Client()
request = FuelSDK.ET_DataExtension()
request.auth_stub = myClient
request.props = {"CustomerKey" : "Vishal_FuelDE"}
request.options = {"Client": {"ID": "11000xxxx"}}

request.columns = [{"CustomerKey" : "[Vishal_FuelDE].[Country]","Name" : "Country_code", "FieldType" : "Text"}]

response = request.patch()

# Print out the results for viewing
print('Post Status: ' + str(response.status))
print('Code: ' + str(response.code))
print ('Message: ' + str(response.message))
print('Result Count: ' + str(len(response.results)))
print('Results: ' + str(response.results))
```